# RxJava - Observers don't get onNext() items after a while

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a system made up of several interconnected components. Everything works well for a while, but after a certain amount of time, a couple of observers stop receiving the items sent by an observable's onNext().

A simplified scenario is like this: I have 
`Component1.start()` -> creates a ConnectableObservable with `Observable.create(...).subscribeOn().observeOn().publish()`, and subscribes Component2. After that, it connect()s. This observable emits some items in a loop and then invokes `s.onComplete()` when it finishes.

Component2 implements Observer. In addition it has a ConnectableObservable that runs a while(true) loop. When it gets a value in its onNext(), called by Component1, it notifies Component0 using its own ConnectableObservable. (NOTE I also implemented them with PublishSubject and the same happens).

```
Component1.start() //Creates Component1's ConnectableObservable, subscribes Component2 and starts running with connect();

Component1.connectableObservable -> onNext() ---> Component2 

Component2.connectableObservable -> onNext() ---> Component0
```

When Component0.onNext() gets a particular item (after 100 iterations), it stops Component1.observable, making it exit its loop and call onComplete().

After some time, Component0 calls Component1.start() and everything starts again.

What I've seen is that, **when everything is ok** Component1.observable.onNext() calls `rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.......subscriber.onNext()`

```
rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn

@Override
public void call(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
    final Worker inner = scheduler.createWorker();
    subscriber.add(inner);

    inner.schedule(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

            Subscriber<T> s = new Subscriber<T>(subscriber) {
                @Override
                public void onNext(T t) {
                    subscriber.onNext(t);
```

subscriber.onNext() is the inner class `private static final class ObserveOnSubscriber<T>` and here ends up invoking schedule():

```
@Override
public void onNext(final T t) {
    if (isUnsubscribed() || finished) {
        return;
    }
    if (!queue.offer(on.next(t))) {
        onError(new MissingBackpressureException());
        return;
    }
    schedule();
}
```

schedule() is

```
protected void schedule() {
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
        recursiveScheduler.schedule(this);
    }
}
```

counter is 0 so `recursiveScheduler.schedule(this);` is invoked and Component2 gets the item.

Now, **when it stops working what happens is that counter isn't 0 anymore**, actually every call increments it. Thus, `recursiveScheduler.schedule(this);` is never called and Component2 doesn't get anything.

What could be the cause of this? Why is counter 0 and at some point starts increasing?

**UPDATE**: Digging in the source code I've seen the following: after schedule() is called, there's a scheduled task that invokes the code below, decreasing counter when the items haven't been missed:

```
private static final class ObserveOnSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> implements Action0 {

    // only execute this from schedule()
    @Override
    public void call() {
        ...
            emitted = currentEmission;
            missed = counter.addAndGet(-missed);
            if (missed == 0L) {
                break;
            }
```

According to this, since the items are missed, counter increases and then subsequent items are also missed.

What could be the reason why items are missed?

I've noticed something weird. If I remove any of the other (not mentioned) observables from the program, no items are missed ever. They have Component0 as observer and produce their items in their own subscribeOn() thread so I can't see how they affect this scenario.

**UPDATE 2:** I've kept trying to find out what happens. When I do `Component1.connectableObservable.connect()`, it ends up calling `private static final class ObserveOnSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> implements Action0 -> init()`

Here schedule() is called:

```
void init() {
            // don't want this code in the constructor because `this` can escape through the 
            // setProducer call
            Subscriber<? super T> localChild = child;

            localChild.setProducer(new Producer() {

                @Override
                public void request(long n) {
                    if (n > 0L) {
                        BackpressureUtils.getAndAddRequest(requested, n);
                        schedule();
```

The right behaviour leaves OperatorObserveOn.counter = 0 after schedule(). When it doesn't work anymore, scheduler() increases +1 the value of OperatorObserveOn.counter.

Answer (score 0):

Get the observer for every subscription and create a listener to tell you when one observer unsubscribe from the observable, then you can understand why this is happening.

In your case anyway I would take a look to **Relay**, since you dont have to unsubscribe your observable it´s more secure, and you can be sure it will never stop emitting events.

Take a look of this example.

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/relay/Relay.java

Comment: Hi Paul, how can I create an unsubscribe listener for a class implementing Obsever?

Comment: Take a look to the last test example here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableSubscription.java